# How do you remove all occurrences of values in one list from another list?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, awk

I have a list of symbols such as...

```
wer
sfe
efo
```

How do I remove all instances of these (unique) symbols from another list of (non-unique) symbols?

So in the following list, the lines starting with `wer` would be removed twice, and `sfe` once:

```
wer-alskjdfi
efr-4siosejf
rte-alskjdfs
wer-alskjsef
sfe-ooskjdfi
```

Every other line should be untouched, with the symbol and characters after "-" remaining:

```
efr-4siosejf
rte-alskjdfs
```

I need to do this using sed/awk/grep/bash or other command line tools. I know how to write a sed command to search and remove one value at a time, but how do I do this for 100k+ values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if file 2 has characters after each of those symbols?  I want to do the same but keep the trailing characters.

OK, make a copy of `file2` that has only the field that you want to filter on. 
And, if the current `file2` has the “non-unique symbol” *immediately* followed
by the “trailing characters” (e.g., `efr-42`, `rte-17`, etc.),
make another copy of `file2` where they are space-separated. 
Here are example commands based on the example data you provided:

```
sed 's/\(...\).*/\1/'        file2.sorted > file2.symbol_only
sed 's/\(...\)\(.*\)/\1 \2/' file2.sorted > file2.separated
```

or

```
sed 's/\([^-]*\)-.*/\1/'        file2.sorted > file2.symbol_only
sed 's/\([^-]*\)\(-.*\)/\1 \2/' file2.sorted > file2.separated
```

… based on the new data that you added to your question. 
Then use `comm` as before:

```
comm -13 file1.sorted file2.symbol_only > file2.no_match
```

… and join the symbols up with the trailing characters:

```
join file2.no_match file2.separated
```

If necessary, use another `sed` to remove the spaces you added.

---

It occurs to me that you could build on this trick to get the output file back into `file2`’s original order.

1. Produce a copy of the original `file2` with line numbers.
2. Shuffle the line numbers to the right of the symbols.
3. *(the above, starting with the `sort` commands)*
4. Sort the output on the original line number.
5. Strip out the line numbers.

Let me know if you need help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your lists reside in files

```
awk -F- 'NR==FNR {exclude[$1]++; next} !($1 in exclude)' list_of_symbols filename
```

grep is also an option

```
grep -v -f <(sed 's/^/^/' list_of_symbols) filename
```

The sed bit adds a regexp anchor to the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to retain the order of your second file? 
Can you state a maximum number of times that a line can be repeated? 
If the answers to both questions are “no”, I’d suggest `comm`:

```
sort file1 file1 > file1.sorted     sort file2 > file2.sorted
-------------------------------     -------------------------
efo                                 efr
efo                                 rte
sfe                                 sfe
sfe                                 wer
wer                                 wer
wer

comm -13 file1.sorted file2.sorted
efr
rte
```

Include enough copies of `file1` in `file1.sorted` to cover the maximum number of occurrences of any string in `file2`.

Comment: thanks Scott. What if file 2 has characters after each of those symbols? I want to do the same but keep the trailing characters.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about SED etc, the basic design in my personal pseudocode is:

sort the list of strings to be removed (List A)

sort the list of strings which contains items to be removed (List B)

For each item in List A

```
Repeat until Item (List B) > Item (List A)
    if the Item (List B) equals Item (List A) 
        remove item (List B)
    next Item (List B)
Next Item (List A)
```

Note: "Removing" an item might be problematical - better to replace this line with one adding the item to a new